# Passive / light-weight / serializable translatables?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

So.. in Drupal 8 we have several classes that implement `\Drupal\Core\TypedData\TranslatableInterface`, and we have `Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup`.

Each of these classes contain references to services that will actually do the translation, making them heavy on e.g. `var_export()` or `serialize()`.

Is there a class to store an untranslated string plus replacements plus options, that does not contain these dependencies?

Maybe `\Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation` does get close, but I think it  is only meant for annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.drupal.org/node/2893029.

Ther isn't really a workaround until that is fixed.

Comment: Interesting. I had a quick look at this. The problem seems that we want to have the cake and eat it, too. Meaning, we want an object that can translate itself, while at the same time being serializable. Instead, I am looking for a class that cannot translate itself, and only contains the raw untranslated data. I guess I am going to write this myself.